# Jquery Animate to top not animating properly in IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have an image with text. On clicking on the arrows the text has to go top. It is working fine in firefox. The transition is smooth in firefox. But their is a Jerky in IE. please tell me what is wrong in the below code? How to make the transition smooth in all the browser?

```
var r = '-500';
                                $('#innerContainer').find('.current .overlay').animate({    
                                        top: r,
                                        bottom:'0'

                                      },{ queue:false, duration:speed});    
                            }
```

And also what is queue:false will do?

Answer (score 0):

`queue:false` makes it so that the animations don't add up, like a line, executing each until finished. It means that it'll stop the current one if animate is called again on the same element.

For the IE issue trying adding `px` to the value and see if that changes anything.

Comment: Thanks @brenjt. I have given px, now what happens was it goes first to a point and sticks there and then animate it...